# 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' for UIToolbar

Tags: ios, swift, runtime-error

I created a toolbar **programatically**. However, I get the error 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' for my toolbar at `toolbar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width: 250, height: 20)` . I'm made sure I didn't declare toolbar twice, so I don't understand why I'm getting this.

```
var toolbar : UIToolbar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    toolbar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width: 250, height: 20)
    toolbar.center = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
    self.view.addSubview(toolbar)
}
```

Comment: well... you never actually *create* the toolbar.... do `toolbar = UIToolbar()` somewhere (preferably before you set stuff on it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var toolbar : UIToolbar!
```

only declare your toolbar variable as a UIToolbar. You still did not create it. Therefore, when you call `toolbar.frame` inside `viewDidLoad()` you got the error.

call `toolbar = UIToolbar()` before calling `toolbar.frame` to create the UIToolbar instance first

```
var toolbar = UIToolbar()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    toolbar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width: 250, height: 20)
    toolbar.center = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
    self.view.addSubview(toolbar)
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem a need for toolbar to be implicitly unwrapped, so instead of taking the risk it'd be better to do: `var toolbar = UIToolbar()`.

Comment: that is true as well